# Simple java calculator

Tags: java, swing

I had created a basic calculator using Java Swing. The question I have is how to print each calculation on the panel. for example, I have added two numbers, my panel should look something like 2 + 4 = 6, and if I perform another operation it should append another operation in the panel.

My idea: I know I can do with the labels and change the value of the labels, but this is not a good idea since as the operations increase I cannot keep on adding the labels, I believe there should be a way but since I am learning Swing, I need some help from experts.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean by "as the operations increase I cannot keep on adding the labels"?

Comment: this isn't a "give me teh codez" site, you need to show your work, explain what isn't working and ask specific questions ... or your question will get closed.

Comment: @Charlesworth: What I mean is I have few operations like 2+3=5, 2/2=1,3-4=-1 etc., I have print all these operations on the jpanel and not just one recent operation. I can do with labels by assigning values to the labels, but I need all the operations I had performed lets say 100. How do I dynamically add these operations to my panel is the question I have.

Comment: @Roberson: Please, don't be so rude on me. I am not asking for experts to write the code for me, I need the hint or a suggestion so that I can keep track of all the operations I had performed.

Comment: Seeing that you need as much as 100 operations then you need to store these in some data structure such as a List, but displaying them might be a problem. Using the JTextArea as I mentioned in the answer is possible if you put it in a JScrollPAne so that the user can scroll through the operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use a JTextArea and set it to be non-editable. The text area control will allow you to add multiple lines of text so that you can keep appending operations as you like.

   textArea.setEditable(false);
2. Draw the text as graphics on a Canvas. This is a little more involved but you have more control over the way the text look and how it is formatted.

   g.drawString("a + b = c", x, y);

Comment: An important unmentioned advantage of the JTextArea option - the user will be able to easily copy/paste the results

Comment: Appending to textfield works like a charm :). Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The panel will most likely read from a String.  Try using [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) to append to the String as input is being entered.

This way, you can also modify/delete the final " = 6" and add another "+ 6 = 10" if you choose to add more operations.  Then use toString() when you want to refresh the final outcome on the panel without creating a whole new String.

Answer (score 0):

Either make one JLabel and instead of adding new ones and displaying those, you can get the text using getText() on the JLabel, then append the text you want to add and finally use setText() sending your new and complete text so that the one JLabel has all text in it.
OR
You could make a JPanel or JComponent (something that you can draw on with paintComponent(Graphics g) and use g.drawString() that takes a string to draw (which would be your full appended text) and the x, y location at which to draw e.g. 
g.drawString("2 + 6 = 8", 100, 120);
and you would have to call repaint() on the component in order to update the text. make sure you can store the string somewhere the component can access while drawing.

I hope this helps.